# How to best configure a home network with one dedicated firewall PC, and two routers (one linked to the other to increase range)?

Tags: router, wireless-router, firewall, untangle

I have a moderately complex home network, but I'm not getting the data I want from my firewall, which sends nightly reports of activity.

My entry point to my network is an Untangled server with 2 NICs, in and out.

The out leads to a Linksys WRT54G, which services three wired computers, and a line out to another router, a DLink DIR-645, located in a different part of the house to increase range. The network functions, but not in the way I want.

Both routers currently handle dynamic DHCP, in different ranges on the 192.168.1 block (the Linksys is responsible for 100-150, the DLink for 200-250). However, I want the Firewall to be responsible for all IP allocations, because then it can generate reports of traffic in and out of the network.

The firewall doesn't seem capable of dynamic DHCP assignments (only static ones, that I can see), but I don't want to have to manually configure every new device that connects to my network.

So, specifically, I have 2 questions:

1) How do I configure my Untangled server to do Dynamic DHCP assignments, and then

2) How can I configure the Linksys and DLink routers to be dumb, just routing traffic to the Firewall and nothing else?

Comment: 2) If it is a wifi AP and maybe the other one also they internal web servers.  **ipconfig /all**  Look for **gateway** Type the ip address of the gateway into a web browser and see if it either **username** and **password** dialog or bring up a config screen.  After entering the user/pass you should enter the config screen.  From there you can turn DHCP server off if you want to and the computer will default to the first server that responds.

Comment: 1) Google found this link to this info http://wiki.untangle.com/index.php/DHCP_Server